# SELECT rows from 2 different tables when match with a column differentiating the table

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to get the rows that matchs with a string from 2 different columns. With the following code I get the right data, but the key of the array belongs always to the first table. I would like to know how to get the differentating both tables, in this case [catid] and [subcatid]:

```
SELECT categoriaid AS catid, categoria AS cat
FROM $this->tcat
WHERE categoria LIKE '%$search%'
UNION
SELECT subcategoriaid AS subcatid, subcategoria AS subcat
FROM $this->tsubcat
WHERE subcategoria LIKE '%$search%'
```

What I get is:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#9484 (2) {
    ["catid"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(20) "Atención a Clientes"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#9483 (2) {
    ["catid"]=>
    string(1) "7"
    ["cat"]=>
    string(20) "Atención al cliente"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying Id 7 belongs to tCat? Are you sure of that, with a union result column names come from the first select. (The SQL looks like prone to injection attacks but I don't know the real use case)

Comment: I don't think you are using the right operation /UNION/ for what you need. Also you are mixing your question. Asking about sql/mysql and your code is something else (php?) so please either tag whatever else you are using or stick with just the technology you have a problem with. So regarding your question a Union operation will always return the data from all tables involved with the naming of the first select in the union operation, regardless of what you named the columns from the second query on (the alias are just ignored there). Try adding what are the table contents and expectation

Comment: You can use join and put you condition with OR condition like where (categoria LIKE '%$search%' or  subcategoria LIKE '%$search%') or get data by separate queries & then merge in desired output format.